# Android Studio: import org.tensorflow.Operation does not seem to work

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am using the latest Android Studio to create an image recognition project. I am using a .pb file downloaded from Github.

I have added "`implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.5.0'`" in build.gradle file.

When I go to the java file, the following two import statements are "unused"

```
import org.tensorflow.Operation;

import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;
```

Could somebody help? I am new to TensorFlow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question. I misunderstood what "unused" means.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't have to add your imports manually. Android Studio shows some variants for imports and adds it automatically.
If your imports are grey and you get "unused" that means you didn't use them in this class so you can simply delete them.
It happens sometimes when you decided to write all imports **before** you actually code anything using these classes.
If you leave this warning nothing bad will happen but you use more memory than you actually need.